# Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources' in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Every time I try to build like with

```
 - npx react-native run-android --variant=release
```

but it gives error as :-

```
[drawable-mdpi-v4/src_images_goback] /Users/office/Documents/nsc-app/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/src_images_goback.png    [drawable-mdpi-v4/src_images_goback] /Users/office/Documents/nsc-app/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/src_images_goback.png: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_nsclogo] /Users/office/Documents/nsc-app/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/assets_nsclogo.png   [drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_nsclogo] /Users/office/Documents/nsc-app/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/assets_nsclogo.png: Error: Duplicate resources
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean the drawable folder using the gradle wrapper (gradlew) in your project directory.

1. cd into the "android" folder,

> `cd android`

2. run command:

> `./gradlew clean`

- **(Not suggested)** You can also remove the drawable folder through cmd:

> `rm -rf ./android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi`

Comment: I tried all of them but nothing is working at last it is giving same error.

Comment: Check this suggestion as well: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/22234#issuecomment-437812451

Comment: I used that too. but it also didn't worked well.

Comment: @RajivChaulagain One last shot :P. Try  npx react-native run-android --mode release, since --variant is deprecated